Ansible loop through all the Worker nodes
I need to patch my Kubernetes Worker nodes with correct annotations, and I have script below:
---
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: false
    remote_user: opc
    environment: 
      KUBECONFIG: "/home/opc/.kube/config"
      PATH: "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
      OCI_CLI_AUTH: instance_principal
    
    tasks:
      - name: Get a list of all the nodes
        kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
          kind: node
        register: node_list

      - name: Display k8s Worker Node Name
        debug:
          var: node_list | json_query(query)
        vars:
          query: 'resources[].{name: metadata.name}'
        register: node

The script runs fine and displays the following output:
TASK [Display k8s Worker Node Name] ***************************************************
ok: [40.233.80.218] => {
"node_list | json_query(query)": [
     {
      "name": "172.16.107.244"
     },
     {
     ]"name": "172.16.111.95"
     }
]
}

I need to take the two hosts name and run a kubectl patch node {{name}} command on both. Need some idea on a loop to execute the command locally from the ansible host.

Create an inventory script to list the worker nodes. Then you can just use regular tasks in playbooks.
